# Why Segmentation fault is happening in this situation? Openmp problems

Tags: c, openmp

After writing a sequential program, I need to parallelize it. Here is a small part, which for some reason does not work. When `N > 64` and 4 threads, the program starts to produce a segmentation error. And with 2 threads everything works fine. I tried to set the environment variable `KMP_STACK_SIZE = 128m`, but this did not help me. What could be the problem?

```
#include <omp.h>
void setMatrix(double *matrix, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (i == j) {
                matrix[i * size + j] = 2;
            } else
                matrix[i * size + j] = 1;
        }
}

void setVector(double *vector, int size, int value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        vector[i] = value;
    }
}

void clearVec(double *vector, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        vector[i] = 0;
    }
}

void mulMatrAndVec(double *result, const double *matrix, const double *vector, int size) {
    clearVec(result, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            result[i] += matrix[i * size + j] * vector[j];
        }
    }
}


void subVectors(double *result, const double *vector1, const double *vector2, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        result[i] = vector1[i] - vector2[i];
    }
}
void mulMatrAndVecMP(double *result, const double *matrix, const double *vector, int place, int blockSize, int size) {
    for (int i = place; i < (place + blockSize); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            result[i] += matrix[i * size + j] * vector[j];
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int N = 68;

    double *A = (double *) malloc(N * N * sizeof(double));
    double *x = (double *) malloc(N * sizeof(double));
    double *b = (double *) malloc(N * sizeof(double));
    double *u = (double *) malloc(N * sizeof(double));
    double *r1 = (double *) malloc(N * sizeof(double));
    double *r2 = (double *) malloc(N * sizeof(double));
    double *z = (double *) malloc(N * sizeof(double));
    double *vec1 = (double *) malloc(N*N * sizeof(double));
    double *vec2 = (double *) malloc(N * sizeof(double));

    double a = 0;
    double bt = 0;

    int threadNum, threadCount;

    setMatrix(A, N);
    setVector(x, N, 0);
    setVector(b, N, N + 1);

    mulMatrAndVec(vec1, A, x, N);
    subVectors(r1, b, vec1, N);
    clearVec(vec1, N);

    memcpy(z, r1, N * sizeof(double));
    memcpy(r2, r1, N * sizeof(double));

    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    threadCount = omp_get_num_threads();


    #pragma omp parallel  private(threadNum) shared(threadCount, vec1, A, z)
    {
        threadNum = omp_get_thread_num();
        mulMatrAndVecMP(vec1, A, z, (threadNum * N) / threadCount, N / threadCount, N);
    }

    free(A);
    free(x);
    free(b);
    free(r1);
    free(r2);
    free(z);
    free(vec1);
    free(vec2);

    free(u);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and turn your code into a [MCVE] (add `#include`s and maybe other information so your program can be compiled)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you call

```
threadCount = omp_get_num_threads();
```

outside the parallel block so it's 1 and your loop inside

```
mulMatrAndVecMP(vec1, A, z, (threadNum * N) / threadCount, N / threadCount, N);
```

goes out of bounds.

Setting

```
threadCount = 4
```

instead should fix your problem.

As you can read [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/omp_005fget_005fnum_005fthreads.html) the call returns the number of threads in the current team, and there's no current team.

Edit: be careful in case N is not divisible by the number of threads: your code skips some lines of the multiplication.